# Include pie chart and sankey diagram in Google Charts dashboard

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I'm trying to combine two charts and a filter, specifically a Pie Chart and Sankey Diagram with no success. There is a similar answered question, but the difference with my problem is that I am embedding my charts inside a dashboard so I can use the slicer filter.

I have tried several ideas to solve it but only the Pie Chart and the slicer appear or simply nothing appears.

Ideas I have tried:

1. Passing only the columns I need in the **view** property of the ChartWrapper class.
2. Naming the columns and casting the data types as shown in the examples for the Sankey diagram
3. Passing only the data I need to the Sankey through the **dataTable** property of the ChartWrapper class

For the moment, I have used the sample code from Google Charts documentation. What I am trying to do is to make appear both charts, so I can arrange de visualizations in the dashboard and then use my own data.

Thanks for the help!

Sample code bellow:

I include the loader in the **partials/header** file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

```
<%- include("partials/header"); -%>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
  google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart', 'controls', 'sankey']
  });

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
  // passes in the data and draws it.
  function drawDashboard() {

    // Create our data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Donuts eaten');
    data.addColumn('string', 'From');
    data.addColumn('string', 'To');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
    data.addRows([
      ['Michael', 5, 'A', 'X', 2],
      ['Elisa', 7, 'A', 'Y', 7],
      ['Robert', 3, 'A', 'Z', 6],
      ['John', 2, 'B', 'X', 1],
      ['Jessica', 6, 'B', 'Y', 9],
      ['Aaron', 1, 'B', 'Z', 4],
      ['Margareth', 8, 'C', 'X', 4]
    ]);

    // Create a dashboard.
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
      document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

    // Create a range slider, passing some options
    var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
      'containerId': 'filter_div',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Donuts eaten'
      },
      'view': {
        'columns': [0, 1]
      }
    });

    // Create a pie chart, passing some options
    var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'PieChart',
      'containerId': 'chart_div',
      'options': {
        'width': 300,
        'height': 300,
        'pieSliceText': 'value',
        'legend': 'right'
      },
      'view': {
        'columns': [0, 1]
      }
    });


    var sankeyChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'Sankey',
      'containerId': 'sankey_div',
      'options': {
        'width': 600
      },
      'view': {
        'columns': [2, 3, 4]
      }
    });
    // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
    // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
    // given the chosen slider range.
    dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, pieChart, sankeyChart);

    // Draw the dashboard.
    dashboard.draw(data);
  }
</script>

<div id="dashboard_div">
  <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
  <div id="filter_div"></div>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <div id="sankey_div" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
</div>

<%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
```

Comment: the `bind` method should only have two arguments, pass the charts in an array --> `dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, [pieChart, sankeyChart]);`